# HTTPS error - You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have an eCommerce WordPress site using woo commerce. Now my hosting company "Heart Internet" provide free SSL certs however the map a subdomain to my domain to achieve this.

Real domain http://mywebsite.com/

SSL Version https://web110.secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com/

So this means if I want to use SSL for my checkout page I need to link to this url. https://web110.secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com/checkout

However doing so provides me with the error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) Server at web115.secure-secure.co.uk Port 80

So I would imagine this is something to do with .htaccess but I am not sure.

If I go to this url: https://web110.secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com

It actually does display the home page, however minus any images or css styles and my console is full of failed to load resources error messages.

AFter contacting my hosting company they have said its due to how the site itself is configured. But this is just a simple wordpress website, nothing fancy going on.

Does any one know what I can do?

Image of heart internet ssl

[image]

To clarify my question is not about css/images not showing up on homepage, its about the fact i cannot reach any other page on my website without getting the error - You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the same certificat,  but with mine 
(Free let's encrypt), i have the same url for whole website. I use woocommerce and checked the appopriate option in the woocommerce setting (use ssl for check out).

Does your provider told you to put your files in this folder ?
If so, all your install might be inside and a redirect done to the main domaine name. You maybe need to change files and folder permissions to use it, with your mostly like ftp browser.